# Modifying an object in a List

Tags: c#, list

How do you modify an object in a List where you don't know what the index will be? Everything I've found about modifying object has been when you know the index that you want to change. So in the code below, it will replace the ServiceRequest at index 0 with the new ServiceRequest 'r' (at least I think it will). But what if you aren't sure what index the user will choose to change?

```
public class ManagementSystem
{

   List<ServiceRequest> Requests = new List<ServiceRequest>();

   public void CreateRequest(ServiceRequest r)
   {           
       Requests.Add(r);          
   }

    public void DeleteRequest(ServiceRequest r)
    {            
        Requests.Remove(r);
    }

    public void ModifyRequest(ServiceRequest r)
    {            
        Requests[0] = r;

    }                    

}
```

Comment: You can use `Requests.IndexOf(r)` to get the index.

Comment: Note that `.IndexOf` will find the **same** item. By default, that's the item with the same reference. At the same time, if you have a reference to an object, you can modify it without this method.

Comment: @Alex Oh, no. You already have a reference. Also, you can't use `ref` with reference-type. Describe what behavior you are expecting. What is this `ModifyRequest` supposed to do?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev There's a method that creates a ServiceRequest and adds it to a List. This ServiceRequest has 3 parameters, a name, an ID number and a description.  I have all 3 parameters as strings. The ModifyRequest allows the user to change one or many of the parameters if they wanted to.

Comment: @Alex **allows the user to change one or many of the parameters** How are you going to determine which Request to modify? By ID? If yes, then answer by Arghya C is correct.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I haven't designed the form quite yet. But I plan for it to show all the ServiceRequests after they've been added. Then the user can select the ServiceRequest and change it. So would Arghya C's answer apply to something like this?

Comment: @Alex You will have to modify values by some unique identifier like ID. For me this answer seems correct. Just try it. If it works for you - accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update an item in a `List<T>`, first you have to find that item and the list and then replace.

Example:

```
public void ModifyRequest(ServiceRequest r)
{
    var req = Requests.FirstOrDefault(rs => rs.SomeProperty.Equals(r.SomeProperty));
    if (req != null)
    {
        var idx = Requests.IndexOf(req);
        Requests[idx] = r;
    }
}
```

Here, I'm assuming `Request` class has a property `SomeProperty`, based on which you'll find a matching `Request` object in the list.

Note that

```
var index = Requests.IndexOf(r);
```

will give a non-negative (valid) index only if that item in the list is the same object as `r`. They have to have same reference for `IndexOf()` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
Requests.IndexOf(r) //r being the object you want to modify
```

to get the index of the object you want to modify, then work out the rest from there